# Child component is not calling parent component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a parent component and a child component. I have a function in the parent component that I have bound to the parent and pass it to the child for the child to use it. But, the X button in the child component, which uses the function is unable to call the function.

Before flagging duplicate, please look at my code, as I have looked at other posts, which did not suffice to my problem.

```
class SimulatorProgressPopup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: props.show, data: props.data};
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({show: nextProps.show, data: nextProps.data});
    }

    render() {
        return (<div style={{display: this.state.show, position: "fixed", width: "500px", height:"300px", left:"50%", top:"50%", transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)", border: "1px solid black"}}>
            <button onClick={this.props.close}>X</button>
        </div>)
    }
}

class SingleSimulatorProgress extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {showPopup: false, data: props.data};
        this.popup = this.popup.bind(this);
        this.popupClose = this.popupClose.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({data: nextProps.data});
    }

    popup() {
        this.setState({showPopup: true});
    }

    popupClose() {
        this.setState({showPopup: false});
    }

    render() {
        return (<tr onClick={this.popup}>
            <td>{this.state.data.leId.substring(this.state.data.leId.length - 3, this.state.data.leId.length)}</td>
            <td className={this.state.data.status}>{this.state.data.status}</td>
            <td>{this.state.data.noOfFailedRequest}</td>
            <td>{this.state.data.requestSent}</td>
            <td>{this.state.data.responseReceived}</td>
            <td>{this.state.data.failureRate}</td>
            <td>{this.state.data.avgReqLatencyInMilis}</td>
            <SimulatorProgressPopup show={this.state.showPopup ? "block" : "none"} data={this.state.data} close={this.popupClose}/>
        </tr>)
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using state for props?

Comment: Because I cannot access the props outside the constructor

Comment: thats just not true. you can access the props in the class via `this.props`

Comment: Oh I learnt something new. I am surprised I didn't know that. But unfortunately, that still did not fix my problem.

Comment: I can write up an answer if no one responds in a bit. but i would really recommend you read up on react and how to keep things performant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are not stopping the event from bubbling to the parent listener (the one on the whole row). So what you need to do is prevent it

```
popupClose(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({showPopup: false});
}
```

if you dont do this then you are essentially saying show is false then show is true in one render cycle. so the popup remains unchanged.

[Here's it live in action if you'd like to see](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ERrWXd)

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I think I understand the problem now. I will have a read on the event.persist and even.stopPropagation functions.